# Is adding 'await' to an async method in a synchronous logic block good practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

My `Asp.Net MVC` site in `synchronous` (fetch, display sucess, upload, display success, etc, etc), but I do have one `async` method to call to send a message to my `Azure` service bus queue, to be triggered at a later date by a `Azure` function.

When I call the `asynchronous` method to put the message on the `Azure` queue I want to save the returned sequence in my db so I can cancel the message at a later date if needed. But as far as I'm aware I shouldn't be waiting for an `async` method, especially because I need to display a success to my user fairly quickly. So is the code below that runs the `async` method the best way to perform this type of operation? AFAIK 'await' will wait until the returned value comes back, should I be doing this before I return to the controller and view?

> ScheduleMessageAsync

This code is part of my service class that gets called by my controller

```
internal void SaveEvent(some parameters) {
    // save event details in db
    // now call up class to save message into the Azure queue
    MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue();
    messageQueue.SendMessage(eventId);

    // do some other stuff like send the user a email and return to the controller and show the user his/her new event has been saved
}
```

Now here I have the message code to save the message in the Azure queue

```
public async void SendMessage(int eventId)
{
    string serviceBusConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusConnectionString"];
    string queueName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"];

    var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName); 

    BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage("some test message");
    message.MessageId = eventId.ToString();

    ////newEvent.EventDateTime
    // TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
    // DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now, ts);
    long sequenceToCancel = await queueClient.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(6));

    queueClient.Close();

    // store sequenceToCancel in db table
}
```

Comment: `await`ing `async` will guarantee completion. If you start `async` and then return the request, there is no guarantee that the code inside `async` was actually run.

Comment: so in this case I need to get sequenceToCancel to store it in a db table, from my understanding await will wait until I get the sequence back before continuing?

Comment: correct, this will cause the code to wait.

Comment: so my overall question is, is this advised for a website were in this case the member is registering for a class/event and I have some spinners showing it's thinking. then the user gets a green banner saying 'you have been registered' or should I run this async call in a thread so I can move on as quickly as possible to show the banner and have the message queue method run in the background? I guess it's just a question of architecture here

Comment: You may want to consider marking your method `async Task` instead of `async void`

Comment: what does making it return a async task do for me that waiting doesn't?

Comment: `async` has nothing to do with how you structure your app specifically. What you're asking is 'should i execute the work before i return a result to the user or should i schedule it to be performed in the background SOMEHOW'. The answer will depend on whether the work is critical. E.g. in stock trading, you would really want to ensure you placed that bid before you told somebody you did...

Comment: Returning a task allows consumers of that method to chain awaits down to the framework api.

Comment: 'down to the framework api', what do you mean by that? I will have two awaits because I will be sending two mesages to two different queues eventually. Would that help in my scenario?

Comment: FYI - I'll have two messages to create when a member creates a class/event. One message will be for post class emailing. It will trigger a function to send out emails to students who attended and the other message will trigger a function pre class (~24 hours before) to check if there's a teacher regsitered, if not the system will drop the class/event. So I will create two different messages at the time of the event creation.